# Reading off only a certain part of the argument of a newcommand

Tags: macros

I am using the glossaries-extra package for my list of symbols. For some reason not relevant here I have defined a new command

```
\newcommand{\symb}[3][]{%
\glsxtrnewsymbol[#1]{#2}{#3}%
 }
```

such that my glossary entries are in the form:

```
\symb[description={Set of Smooth Vector Fields}]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}
```

I would like to "transfer" these to my university's thesis template, where they don't use the glossaries package, instead they define an environment where symbols should be entered as:

```
\begin{symbols}

\sym{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}{Set of Smooth Vector Fields}

\end{symbols}
```

This is simply a tabbing environment, it directly prints whatever you write down in the arguments of the command \sym. So my plan was to define something like

```
\renewcommand{\symb}[3][]{%
\glsxtrnewsymbol[#1]{#2}{#3}%
\sym{#3}{\glsdesc{#2}}%
}
```

This works except that using glossaries package somehow messes with another part of the university's style file. Because of this I would like to define

```
 \renewcommand{\symb}[3][]{%
            \sym{#3}{#1}%
    }
```

However I do not want to have "description={Set of Smooth Vector Fields}" for the second argument, I want to have "Set of Smooth Vector Fields". Is there a way to extract only the part "Set of Smooth Vector Fields" from the second argument of \symb?

Solution: A simplified version of @Schrödinger's cat's solution is working for me:

```
\newcommand{\symb}[3][]{%
\def\mysplit##1=##2{\sym{#3}{##2}}%
\expandafter\mysplit#1%
}
```

Comment: Do you possibly have multiple key-value arguments. That is, `description` and possibly others?

Comment: I ask you the same question I already asked Schrödinger's cat: Why `\expandafter` before `\mysplit`? In case that is expandable, this will expand the very first token of `\symb`'s optional argument before carrying out `\mysplit`. In case `\symb`'s optional argument is empty, this will—if that is expandable—expand the first token of what is behind the call to `\symb`, whatever that will be. Why is that needed?

Answer (score 1):

With the following code, the redefined routine `\symb` acts as follows:

Arguments are passed to `\glsxtrnewsymbol` untouched/as they are.

Arguments are passed to `\sym` after extracting the description from `\symb`'s optional argument as follows:

In case that argument does not contain the leading phrase "description=", it is passed as is. (Space-tokens surrounding the entire phrase and/or a space-token between "description" and "=" are taken into account.)

In case that argument does contain the leading phrase "description=", that phrase gets removed.

- In case the remainder consists only of space-tokens or nothing, the extraction-result will be empty/will not consist of any tokens at all.
- In case the remainder consists of a single non-delimited argument, i.e., either of a single non-brace-token or of a set of tokens nested in braces, one level of braces surrounding the entire remainder will be removed if present, then space-tokens surrounding the entire remainder will be removed.
- In case the remainder consists of something else than just a single non-delimited argument, no braces will be removed but spaces surrounding the entire remainder will be removed.

As `\sym` and `\glsxtrnewsymbol` are not available to me, I provided "dummy-definitions" which do nothing but deliver their arguments in detokenized fashion, nested in angle brackets.

I did all this off the cuff, so no warranties. ;-)

Please also notice my comment about your non-redefined `\symb`-routine and about nesting arbitrary material in curly braces `{` and `}` when passing it to another macro where it forms an optional argument.

The whole "mechanism" is implemented without using whatsoever `\if..`...`\else`...`\fi`. Therefore the meachnism will not be confused by macro-arguments that contain unmatched `\if` or `\else` or `\fi`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral0-expansion the result is delivered after two
%% expansion-steps/after two "hits" by \expandafter.
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only spaces):
%%=============================================================================
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo#1{}.}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Exchange two arguments. (From each argument an outermost level of 
%% surrounding braces will be removed if present.)
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does not contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category code 1 or 2:
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category code
%%                                1 or 2>}%
%%                              {a <single non-space token> that does 
%%                                _not_ occur in <token sequence> >}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[4]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }\expandafter\@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
   \UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#4#3#1#2}{}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\@secondoftwo}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter}\expandafter\@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%% until reaching <token sequence>-sequence and spit that out
%% nested in braces.
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#2{{##1}}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@ExtractDescriptionEqual}{description=}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@ExtractDescriptionSpaceEqual}{description =}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@ExtractDescriptionEqualSpace}{description= }%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@ExtractDescriptionSpaceEqualSpace}{description = }%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionEqual}{ description=}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionSpaceEqual}{ description =}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionEqualSpace}{ description= }%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionSpaceEqualSpace}{ description = }%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@ExtractSpace}{ }%
%%=============================================================================
%% Trim all leading and trailing spaces:
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@RemoveSpaces[1]{%
   \romannumeral0\@firstofone{\UD@TrimTrailSpaceLoop{#1}.#1\UD@Bizarre} \UD@Bizarre\relax\UD@Bizarre
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@TrimTrailSpaceLoop{%
  \long\def\UD@TrimTrailSpaceLoop#1#2 \UD@Bizarre#3\relax\UD@Bizarre{%
     \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{%
       \UD@TrimLeadSpaceLoop{#1}%
     }{%
       \@firstofone{\expandafter\UD@TrimTrailSpaceLoop\expandafter{\@gobble#2}#2\UD@Bizarre} \UD@Bizarre\relax\UD@Bizarre
     }%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobblespace{%
  \@firstofone{\def\UD@gobblespace} {}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@TrimLeadSpaceLoop[1]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{ }{.}{\UD@ExtractSpace}{\expandafter\UD@TrimLeadSpaceLoop\expandafter{\UD@gobblespace#1}}{ #1}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract description:
%%=============================================================================    
\newcommand\UD@ExtractDescription[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{ description = }{.}{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionSpaceEqualSpace}{%
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractDescriptionCheckArgAmount\expandafter{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionSpaceEqualSpace#1}%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{ description= }{.}{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionEqualSpace}{%
      \expandafter\UD@ExtractDescriptionCheckArgAmount\expandafter{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionEqualSpace#1}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{ description =}{.}{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionSpaceEqual}{%
        \expandafter\UD@ExtractDescriptionCheckArgAmount\expandafter{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionSpaceEqual#1}%
      }{%
        \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{ description=}{.}{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionEqual}{%
          \expandafter\UD@ExtractDescriptionCheckArgAmount\expandafter{\UD@ExtractSpaceDescriptionEqual#1}%
        }{%
          \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{description = }{.}{\UD@ExtractDescriptionSpaceEqualSpace}{%
            \expandafter\UD@ExtractDescriptionCheckArgAmount\expandafter{\UD@ExtractDescriptionSpaceEqualSpace#1}%
          }{%
            \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{description= }{.}{\UD@ExtractDescriptionEqualSpace}{%
              \expandafter\UD@ExtractDescriptionCheckArgAmount\expandafter{\UD@ExtractDescriptionEqualSpace#1}%
            }{%
              \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{description =}{.}{\UD@ExtractDescriptionSpaceEqual}{%
                \expandafter\UD@ExtractDescriptionCheckArgAmount\expandafter{\UD@ExtractDescriptionSpaceEqual#1}%
              }{%
                \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{description=}{.}{\UD@ExtractDescriptionEqual}{%
                  \expandafter\UD@ExtractDescriptionCheckArgAmount\expandafter{\UD@ExtractDescriptionEqual#1}%
                }{ #1}%
              }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractDescriptionCheckArgAmount[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherBlank\expandafter{\@gobble#1}{ }{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherBlank\expandafter{\@gobbletwo#1}{%
       \UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
       \expandafter\UD@RemoveSpaces\expandafter{\@secondoftwo#1}%
    }{%
      \UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
      \expandafter\UD@RemoveSpaces\expandafter{\@firstoftwo{}#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Your definition of \symb with a modification:
%% When passing arbitrary arguments as optional arguments, I strongly recommend 
%% nesting them in braces for ensuring that nesting of square brackets won't 
%% lead to problems:
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand{\symb}[3][]{%
  \glsxtrnewsymbol[{#1}]{#2}{#3}%  <- Here the content of #1 is arbitrary.
}%                              %     Problems due to nested square brackets
                                %     might occur in case #1 contains
                                %     [ or ]. 
                                %     Some day someone might do something like
                                %     \symb[{description=optional\macro[macro's optional]}]{...}{...}.
                                %     Therefore nest #1 in braces.
                                %     These braces will be removed by LaTeX 
                                %     when processing \glsxtrnewsymbol's 
                                %     optional argument.
                                %     They prevent confusion when it comes
                                %     to nesting optional arguments within
                                %     optional arguments.
%%=============================================================================
%% Redefinition of  \symb:
%%=============================================================================
\renewcommand{\symb}[3][]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@ExtractDescription{#1}}}{ \sym{#3}}%
  \glsxtrnewsymbol[{#1}]{#2}{#3}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Dummy-definition for \glsxtrnewsymbol which displays the arguments verbatim
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\glsxtrnewsymbol[3][]{%
  \par\noindent
  \texttt{\string\glsxtrnewsymbol}'s optional argument: $\langle$\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}$\rangle$
  \par\noindent
  \texttt{\string\glsxtrnewsymbol}'s mandatory argument 1: $\langle$\texttt{\detokenize{#2}}$\rangle$
  \par\noindent
  \texttt{\string\glsxtrnewsymbol}'s mandatory argument 2: $\langle$\texttt{\detokenize{#3}}$\rangle$
  \par
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Dummy-definition for \sym which displaysthe arguments verbatim
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\sym[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \texttt{\string\sym}'s mandatory argument 1: $\langle$\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}$\rangle$
  \par\noindent
  \texttt{\string\sym}'s mandatory argument 2: $\langle$\texttt{\detokenize{#2}}$\rangle$
  \par
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\vspace*{-1in}%
\noindent
\texttt{\detokenize{\symb[description={Set of Smooth Vector Fields}]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}}}:

\smallskip

\symb[description={Set of Smooth Vector Fields}]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}

\bigskip

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\bigskip

\noindent
\texttt{\detokenize{\symb[ description = { Set of Smooth Vector Fields } ]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}}}:

\smallskip

\symb[ description = { Set of Smooth Vector Fields } ]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}

\bigskip

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\bigskip

\noindent
\texttt{\detokenize{\symb[description = Set of Smooth Vector Fields ]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}}}:

\smallskip

\symb[description = Set of Smooth Vector Fields ]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}

\bigskip

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\bigskip

\noindent
\texttt{\detokenize{\symb{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}}}:

\smallskip

\symb{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}

\bigskip

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\bigskip

\noindent
\texttt{\detokenize{\symb[whatsoever]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}}}:

\smallskip

\symb[whatsoever]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is something that does that. Obviously I do not have your `\sym` command, so I use something for it which shows that it got the arguments right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\def\forgetit{}
\newcommand{\symb}[3][]{%
\glsxtrnewsymbol[#1]{#2}{#3}%
}
\newcommand{\sym}[2]{first argument=\ensuremath{#1},second argument=#2}
\renewcommand{\symb}[3][\forgetit]{%
\def\mysplit##1=##2;{\def\mylast{##2}}%
\ifx#1\forgetit
\sym{#3}{empty}%
\else
\expandafter\mysplit#1;%
\sym{#3}{\mylast}%
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\symb[description={Set of Smooth Vector Fields}]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}

\symb{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This assumes that, whenever the first argument is nonempty, it contains an `=` sign. You can make it immune against that, but then I would recommend using some key management system. For instance, if you are already loading `pgf` it will be very simple.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I did not understand it yet, but I have realized I made some mistake in my question, for the last command lines I wrote I wanted to say \renewcommand{\symb}[3][]{%
            \sym{#3}{#1}%
    } Please see the corrected form

Comment: @E.SeymaKutluk Doesn't the code do that already? It invokes `\sym{#3}{<second part of #1>}`.

Comment: Sorry I guess that part is ok. So instead of trying to understand your code, I have tried it. I get this error: <argument> ... \@tempdima \@parboxrestore \mylast
\@@par
l.43 ...erivative}]{dad}{\ensuremath{d^{\dagger}}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.  "The control sequence at the end of the top line.." is \mylast.

Comment: @E.SeymaKutluk This happens if there is no complete MWE. My code does what you were asking it to do. Now you marry it to macros that I do not know, and there are errors. If you want to avoid this, provide a complete but minimal example that shows what you are doing.

Comment: 1) In your code you have `\ifx#1\forgetit`. I suggest changing to `\ifx\forgetit#1`, just in case `#1`  is something like `\relax\relax...`  2) Why the `\expandafter` in `\expandafter\mysplit#1;%` ? 3) Why defining `\mysplit` inside the redefinition of `\symb` instead of defining it outside that redefinition?

Comment: @UlrichDiez 1) might be better, yes, 2) because otherwise there can be problems 3) because I want to tie this split to this macro, if there are other similar problems around this will be fine because each of them has their own `\mysplit` version which is tailored for that and most importantly 4) both of us are guessing here because the OP do not provide a complete MWE. So what you are doing might be better or worse, we can really not know unless there is an MWE that shows what packages are loaded.

Comment: Ok a simplified version of this suggestion works for me now. Please see the edited question. I dont know if providing a MWE is useful here, this would involve a full new style file provided by the university.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Ad 2) I assume so. ;-) But at the moment I don't get which problems. Therefore obviously I am overlooking something obvious. I often do so. My question aimed at learning what it is. Ad 3) `\mysplit` will be (re)defined (not within a new group/scope but within the current scope) whenever `\symb` is carried out. Probably this is not the most frugal way of handling memory ressources. But nowadays you don't have to be all too frugal in the handling of memory ressources any more... ;-)

Comment: @E.SeymaKutluk In case the style file provided by the university is publicly available, you could probably provide a link to it along with the MWE. This way one could try to track down the reason for which things don't work well with the glossaries package. In this case applying `\listfiiles` and providing an excerpt of your .log-file showing the versions of packages loaded might be helpful, too.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Ad 4) The questioner asked about a routine which would extract things and pass them to a routine `\sym`.  Seems to me to be a well-defined task. The guessing is about why things don't work with the glossaries package.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Try `\def\a{description={Set of Smooth Vector Fields}}
\symb[\a]{vfs}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{X}}}` with and without `\expandafter`. And no, I disagree with the statement that we have all information. If I knew that the OP loads pgf, this could be made much more elegant.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat toplevel-expansion in case the optional argument is a macro, I see. ;-)  So you can always get things properly expanded into a temporary macro and then pass that to `\symb`. Thanks for the clarification.